# Creating a parent reference to child object in JNI invocation API with C++

Tags: c++, syntax, java-native-interface, parent-child, invocation

I'm rather new to JNI invocation API so I am still slightly confused by it. I have a Java library from which I would normally create a parent object reference to a child like this:

```
Cake mycake = CakeFactory.getchocolatecake();
```

Where getchocolatecake() is a static method that returns an object inherited from the Cake class.

How exactly do I go about trying to achieve the same in C++ using the JNI invocation API?